# Fatal error from phpmailer class

Tags: php, upload, phpmailer

I have made a php page that sends an email message with multiple attachments. 
The loop which i used to attach multiple attachments and to check the size of attachments is ,

```
foreach(array_keys($_FILES['attach']['name']) as $key) 
{  
    $filesize = $_FILES['attach']['size'][$key];
    $extention = pathinfo ($_FILES['attach']['name'][$key] ,PATHINFO_EXTENSION
             );
    $name=$_FILES['attach']['name'][$key];
    $data=($_FILES['attach']['tmp_name']);
    $totalsize = $totalsize + $filesize;

if($totalsize > 10000000) //10mb10000000
{$err="<font color=#990000 size=1>File exceeded maximum allowed limit of 10
     Mb</font>";}
else{
$source = $_FILES['attach']['tmp_name'][$key];
$filename = $_FILES['attach']['name'][$key];
$mail->AddAttachment($source, $filename);
    }
}//end Foreach loop
```

But when i try to attach a large file i get this error from the phpmailer class.

```
  Fatal error: Allowed memory size of 16777216 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate
  7355049 bytes) in /var/www/dev01/maiarn/Email/class.phpmailer.php on line 1677
```

Any body who can guide me Please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might want to increase the PHP memory limit. If you're working on your development machine, you could search for the php.ini file and modify the memory_limit (which often defaults to 16M). Change that to f.e. 128M and restart your webserver.

If you want to see it change, you can use the following line to show the configuration currently in use:

```
<?php phpinfo(); ?>
```

Comment: If i want to use the default memory for my attachments, then what should i place in if($totalsize > 10000000), this is bytes for 10Mb, smaller than 16M

Comment: For sending a file as e-mail attachment, PHP needs to encode the data using MIME encoding, which usually adds 33% to the original datasize. All depends of how everything is buffered, so this is really unpredictable. Also request to your website from other users can use pieces of the PHP memory. So, I think it's best to increase the memory limit to a much higher value.

Comment: If your working on a remote server, add this to the .htaccess file: `php_value memory_limit 128M` then check if you've overwritten the value with `<?php phpinfo(); ?>`. Not all server configurations allow you to override values with a .htaccess file.

Comment: i have seen my remote server configs, and it has its memory limit to 16M, please wud u tell me where is this .htaccess file, i can't find it.

Comment: you just add the .htaccess yourself in the root directory of your website. Do some search on .htaccess.

Answer (score 0):

Let PHP use more memory on this script only by using the following PHP code:

```
ini_set(‘memory_limit’,’64M’);
```